# Core Data: Returning to a Previously Inserted Managed Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have the following model:

```
Doctor <-->> Case <->> Report
```

A Doctor has many Cases but a Case has only one Doctor. A Case can has many Reports

I successfully generated the classes representing my model, and I inserted one Doctor, with one Case with one Report.

How can I return to this Doctor and associate another Case and the same for a Report?

Any example for one-to-many Core Data insertion and display.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a managed object you get a pointer to that object back. Assuming you have a NSManagedObject subclass of Doctor, you would create a new Doctor object like this:

```
Doctor *newDoc=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Doctor" 
                                               inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
```

`newDoc` is now a pointer to the `Doctor` object and you can treat it like any other object. You can retain a reference to it any way you like e.g. instance attribute, array, set etc. You can then retrieve it and add new Case object like so:

```
[newDoc addCaseObject:aNewCase];
```

...and the same to add a Report to a case. These methods are defined in the autogenerated subclasses.